# Правильно ли такое выражение: "Хочу пригласить Вас на важное событие"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Правильно ли такое выражение:"** Хочу **пригласить** вас на важное **событие**"? Или можно пригласить только на встречу или мероприятие?

Comment: Очевидно, нет. Звучит коряво. Мероприятие можно назвать событием в каком-то переносном значении. Но нельзя потом на это событие приглашать, как на мероприятие. Сравните: Жизнь - игра. Игра зародилась 4 млрд лет назад.

Answer (score 1):

Допустимость такого выражения зависит от того, что подразумевается под "**событием**". Событием не является день рождения или свадьба (как торжественный ужин). Это должно быть нечто с неизбежностью *изменяющее ситуацию в присутствии приглашаемого* - ожидается, что "сбудется" что-то особенное. Например, говорящий публично побъет какой-то рекорд для книги Гиннесса, подпишет важный договор (по меньшей мере, о заключении брака; в этом смысле свадьба - лишь *мероприятие*, на котором отмечают формально произошедшее *событие*), получит награду, прилюдно заберется на небоскреб и т. п.

Comment: Не уверен, что "приглашаю вас на побитие (событие) рекорда" корректно. Потому что побитие это точечное событие, не имеющее продолжительности. Правильно будет "приглашаю вас на лицезрение побития (события) рекорда" или "приглашаю вас на побивание (событивание) рекорда". Ну это я включил зануду.

Comment: Приглашение не на "побитие" (в такой форме редко приглашают, хотя можно хоть на поедание торта приглашать - в этом нет грамматических проблем), а на ожидаемое или запланированное"событие", смысл которого предложение буквально не раскрывает (это может быть и сюрприз). Содержание "события" может быть любым: таким событием может стать, в частности, обещаемое побитие рекорда.